# Passing object on the table element

Tags: javascript

I am passing an object to the html table TD component for onclick event, however it's not giving me the specific error on the console.

Here is my sample code:

```
let obj = [{"num":"344695","det":0.412913,"inItem":false}]

row += '<tr><td>'
+ '</td><td onclick = "display(' + "'false" + "','" + obj + "'" + ')" >' + "test"
+ '</td></tr>';

 $('#myTable tbody').html(row);


 function display(status, obj){
    console.log(obj)
}
```

It's giving me this kind of error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Comment: This error is often triggered by mismatched braces, brackets, or parens; typos, missing commas, that sort of thing. Your provided sample code executes without error for me in the browser's devtools. I suspect you're missing a bracket or something in the surrounding code.

Comment: do like this first create a variable row `var row = '';` then do the thing your doing `row +='<tr></tr>'`.